# Theme broken after upgrading to WordPress 4.5, missing stylesheet?

Tags: themes, updates

Updating to WordPress 4.5 broke my theme, [ThemeWoot Emulate](http://emulate.themewoot.com/). It appears that perhaps a stylesheet is somehow missing. Example symptoms:

- The mobile menu is shown by default
- The top search box is being shown by default
- The contact form modal is being shown by default
- Various links are underlined and a different font

One thing I noticed was that, in the case where sections should be hidden by default, a `.hide` class is present, but there is no corresponding style being applied to that class.

I tried clearing the server and browser cache. I've tried deactivating all plugins and updating them, but there's no difference.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the ThemeWoot Emulate theme registers and enqueues a `common.css` file with the key of `common` in it's `themewoot.php` (which is being included in `functions.php`).

This key is apparently conflicting with a wp-admin script being registered with the same `common` key, and so, instead of including Emulate's `common.css`, it's enqueuing and injecting the wp-admin `common.min.css`.

I edited the `themewoot.php` and namespaced the `common` key with a an `emulate-` prefix:

**From:**

```
wp_register_style('common', $this->theme_url(). '/css/common.css', false, TWOOT_VERSION, 'all');

wp_enqueue_style('common');
```

**To:**

```
wp_register_style('emulate-common', $this->theme_url(). '/css/common.css', false, TWOOT_VERSION, 'all');

wp_enqueue_style('emulate-common');
```

And that got things back in working order.

ThemeWoot [doesn't appear to be maintaining](http://themeforest.net/item/emulate-multipurpose-responsive-wordpress-theme/6058805) the Emulate theme anymore. In reality they should patch this and provide an update.

**<rant>**
WordPress should seriously consider namespacing their core styles and scripts so that updates don't affect themes like this. A simple `wp-` would have gone a long way here and saved me at least a few hours. Theme creators should also namespace all of their assets too so that they play nice with everything else.
**</rant>**

Comment: +1 for findinhg it, but name spacing is always the responsibility of the plugin and theme authors. if you look around here you will see that even answers here are usually namespaced ;)

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem. The above fixed most of the theme styling however the portfolios and blog shortcodes and category pages are blank. They load the content and then it dissapears once the page fully loaded. Other style sheets maybe not loaded correctly to maybe?

Comment: Hi Rudi, this should really be a comment or a new question, not an answer.